# How to find RC4 key from decrypted and encrypted data?

Tags: c, cryptanalysis, rc4-cipher

I have some dump analysis in a documentation showing a bunch of encrypted data, and the resulting decrypted data. The algorithm used is explained (simple RC4). The only piece of information missing is the key used to get from the encrypted to the decrypted data.

I'm writing an automated test from this documentation material. I could chose some key of my own and recreate encrypted data from cleartext, but I wonder if there is any easy cryptanalysis way to find the original key that was used to encrypt the original bunch of data.

A brute force approach is probably possible as the key is quite small, but I'm much more interrested to know if any smarter approach exists.

Below is my current C encryption code (using OpenSSL):

```
unsigned char source[16] = {
    0xdb, 0xa3, 0x13, 0x30, 0x79, 0xa3, 0xcd, 0x9e,
    0x48, 0xf4, 0x8f, 0x06, 0x37, 0x1b, 0x45, 0xdd};
unsigned char expected_target[16] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x6d, 0x69, 0x63, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x66};
unsigned char target[16] = {};
unsigned char key[16] = {};

RC4_KEY crypt_key;
RC4_set_key(&crypt_key, 16, key);
RC4(&crypt_key, 16, source, target);

printf("key    = [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x "
               "- %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x]\n",
    key[0], key[1], key[2], key[3],
    key[4], key[5], key[6], key[7],
    key[8],  key[9], key[10], key[11],
    key[12], key[13], key[14], key[15]);

printf("source = [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x "
               "- %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x]\n",
    source[0], source[1], source[2], source[3],
    source[4], source[5], source[6], source[7],  
    source[8], source[9], source[10], source[11],
    source[12], source[13], source[14], source[15]);

printf("target = [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x "
               "- %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x]\n",
    target[0], target[1], target[2], target[3],
    target[4], target[5], target[6], target[7],
    target[8], target[9], target[10], target[11],
    target[12], target[13], target[14], target[15]);

printf("expected_target = [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x "
                        "- %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x]\n",
    expected_target[0], expected_target[1], expected_target[2], expected_target[3],
    expected_target[4], expected_target[5], expected_target[6], expected_target[7],
    expected_target[8], expected_target[9], expected_target[10], expected_target[11],
    expected_target[12], expected_target[13], expected_target[14], expected_target[15]);
```

Comment: Brute force? Seriously, though, the whole point of encryption is to make stuff like this computationally hard.

Comment: It's not clear to me. I believed what was proven computationaly hard was to find some unknown clear text given the ciphered text. In my case I have both crypted text and clear text. It's unclear to me that is the same problem (but brute force may indeed not be an option).

Comment: It is the same problem. Known plaintext makes certain attacks easier but in the case of RC4 no such attacks are known. Sorry, but if you don't know the key here you're SOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. There are no efficient RC4-cracking methods known.
2. You need millions of years to brute-force 128-bit key. You could try to use password lists.

Comment: as I know the key is likely to be random number, password list is out of the picture. But I'm not sure what I'm looking for is really RC4 cracking, as I already have cleartext (maybe it is anyway, but I'm still interested on pointers explaining why).

Comment: If key is really random, you have no chance. RC4 is not broken now. Known-plaintext attacks model is not an exception.

Comment: Also, if you have an old RC4 implementation (I think no), you can try a [Fluhrer, Mantin and Shamir attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluhrer,_Mantin_and_Shamir_attack)